# Lists - changing strings to integers in a list imported form CSV, not all data

Tags: python, list, csv, import, int

I have the following code in python 3

```
import csv
import operator

with open('herofull.csv','r') as file:
    reader=csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')
    templist=list(reader)

print(templist)
```

and the data on the csv looks like this

[CSVflie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vx8i.png)

The program imports the data into a list. I then want to change the last 3 items on each row that are now in the list to integers so I can do calculations with them, is this possible? I have tried all sorts with no luck. I can do it with a simple list but this is imported like a list within a list which is making my brain hurt. Please help

Ross

Comment: show the list itself it will be easier...

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest to do a loop, especially if you know it's the last three elements.

```
for row in templist:
    for i in range(-3, 0):
        row[i] = int(row[i])
```

This will not create a new list in memory, instead simply changing the existing `templist`.

Comment: I missed the fact that its 2 loops, list within list, get it now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new list with your data and convert any strings that are digits into integers.

```
new_list = []
for row in templist:
    new_list.append(
        [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in row]
    )

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you know that the last three numbers are always going to contain 2 digits or less, you can do the following:

```
for line in templist:
    for index, element in enumerate(line):
        if element.isdigit() and len(element) <= 2:
            line[index] = int(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

cool...cheers

Had a brain wave and got this to work

```
import csv

with open('herofull.csv','r') as file:
    reader=csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')
    templist=list(reader)

for row in templist:
    row[4]=int(row[4])
    row[5]=int(row[5])
    row[6]=int(row[6])

print(templist)
```

I can now do calculations and append the list, thanks for you help. It appears I just needed to stop thinking about it for while (wood, trees and all that)